# How get last row with different value in some columns in mariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need get last rows (for example `10 rows`)
With different values in some columns (for example in `cat` column ) in mariaDB.

| id | cat | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1 | name1 |
| 2 | val1 | name2 |
| 3 | val2 | name3 |
| 4 | val2 | name4 |
| 5 | val2 | name5 |
| 6 | val3 | name6 |
| 7 | val3 | name7 |
| 8 | val3 | name8 |

**result :**

| id | cat | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | val1 | name2 |
| 5 | val2 | name5 |
| 8 | val3 | name8 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(cat) over (order by id) as next_cat
      from t
     ) t
where next_cat is null or next_cat <> cat;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=7376ea68a5973f2f1828793befd6758b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: error :  `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') over (order by id) as next_cat
      from vid
     ) vid
where next_cat ... at line 3`  my table name (`vid`) and col is (`char`)

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?  MariaDB has supported window functions for many years.

Comment: last MariaDB version (10.5.4)

Comment: @H.jalali . . . The code works as is.  I added a db<>fiddle illustrating this.